# Code challenge about Arrays and strings in pure Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, methods

I am a n00b, and am currently doing some pure Javascript challenges to enter a bootcamp.

We are going over **arrays**, and have learned specifically a few things to complete the hacking challenges, such as:

- Methods, such as: **pop()**, **push()** , **split('')**, **join()** (or **join(' ')** if we want to remove the commas),
- How to console log what's inside arrays and concatenate the values with Strings.
- How to print certain array elements, as so:

```
var petShop = ['Puppies', 'Kitties', 'Hamsters', 'Snakes', 'Birds'];

console.log('In the second cage we have: ' + petShop[1]);

// prints 'In the second cage we have: Kitties'
```

- Array.length
- How to use for loops to print each of the elements of an array, like so:

```
var powerRangers = ['Red', 'Black', 'Yellow', 'Pink', 'Blue'];

for( var i = 0; i < powerRangers.length; i++){
    console.log(i + ':' + powerRangers[i]);
}
```

- we also went through if statements

---

**CHALLENGE**
The challenge states:

Instructions

Copy the uncorrupted data in the array stored in targetDisk to the empty array newDisk (corrupted data looks like this: ø). Then print the contents of the disk to the terminal as a string.

To complete this task remember the arrays' methods we have learned so far.
(which are the ones I wrote above)

**MY CODE**

```
var targetDisk = [ 'E', 'ø', '-', 'C', 'ø', 'o', 'r', 'ø', 'ø', 'p', '\'', 'ø', 's', ' ', 'E', 'v', 'ø', 'i', 'ø', 'ø', 'l'];
var newDisk = [];
var corruptionSymbol = 'ø';

var phrase = targetDisk.join(' ');

console.log('This is the phrase: ' + phrase);

var newPhrase = phrase.split('ø');

console.log('This is the newPhrase: ' + newPhrase);

for( var i = 0; i < newPhrase.length; i++){
    newDisk.push(newPhrase[i]);
      //console.log(newDisk);
}

console.log('This is the newDisk: ' + newDisk.join(''));
```

---

**THE OUTPUT**

> > > > Code is incorrect. Your code is not up to fSociety standards, keep trying to improve it
> > > > This is the phrase: E ø - C ø o r ø ø p ' ø s E v ø i ø ø l
> > > > This is the newPhrase: E , - C , o r , , p ' , s E v , i , , l
> > > > This is the newDisk: E - C o r p ' s E v i l

---

I am thinking that it might be wrong because there are still spaces between the newDisk string - as you can see in the output.

Can someone help me understand what I am doing wrong? How can I remove those spaces between the letters in the final string and have something like so: E-Corp's Evil

Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: The title here does a rather poor job of describing your problem in away that would make it findable by other users with the same problem.

Comment: Hi @KevinB, Thank you for your feedback.
I am still learning, so any constructive suggestions are very welcome - what do you believe would be a best option for a title? :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't `join` or `split`. Just loop over the original array and compare each character with the disallowed symbol. Only call `push` on the new array if it's not that character.

```js
for (let i = 0; i < targetDisk.length; i++)
    if (targetDisk[i] !== corruptionSymbol)
        newDisk.push(targetDisk[i]);
```

This can be done more simply with [`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) as well.

```js
let newDisk = targetDisk.filter(c => c !== corruptionSymbol);
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your explanation @Unmitigated.
I had commented out a block of code that was close to the solution you've posted (if we take out the spelling errors and extra spaces that made it not work :') ). 
Your solution worked perfectly, and the IDE accepted it as correct.

Answer (score 1):

Your current solution is converting the array entries to a string and then attempting to re-create that as an array. That's going to be an error-prone process.

All that you really need to do is run a loop that checks for the presence of your bad character.

```
const targetDisk = [ 'E', 'ø', '-', 'C', 'ø', 'o', 'r', 'ø', 'ø', 'p', '\'', 'ø', 's', ' ', 'E', 'v', 'ø', 'i', 'ø', 'ø', 'l'];

const corruptionSymbol = 'ø';

let newDisk = []

for (const entry of targetDisk) {
    if (entry !== corruptionSymbol) {
        newDisk.push(entry)
    }
}

console.log(newDisk)
```

Also, `var` is bad. Use `const` or `let` instead.

Comment: Hey @Josh, thank you so much for your solution - your explanation actually helped me to better understand the exercise :)

Answer (score 0):

Hey Check out this live demo

```js
targetDisk.forEach((e) => {
  if (e !== corruptionSymbol) newDisk.push(e);
});

console.log(newDisk.join(''))
```

You can use forEach to check the element is matching with the corrupted Symbol or not. Then push it to the new array and join it with join('')

https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-2bzrye?file=index.html,index.js

Comment: I gave it a plus one. It's a good answer. Didn't see that it was trying to re-convert everything back to a string after the fact.

Comment: Thank you. I think there are mulitple ways to solve these kind of things. It is good to see different solutions for things like this. @Josh

Comment: Hey @barisdevjs, thank you for your reply! It is indeed a good answer - however the IDE kept telling me to stick to information we've studied so far only. But it worked! (just not for their specific checks)